# How to convert an embedded JSON file to CSV in pandas python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Hi I have received a JSON file with below format, please let me know how do i parse this JSOn file and convert them to CSV

JSON file format

```
{'Sections': [{'MC': [[{'IsMandatory': False,
      'LD': None,
      'propNameValuepair': [{'PropertyType': 0,
        'columnSize': 0,
        'isEnabled': False,
        'isStructured': False,
        'isUpdated': False,
        'propDisplayName': 'CC',
        'propName': 'u4_c_c',
        'propValue': 'Bottle',
        'selectedComponent': None,
        'tcProperty': None},
       {'PropertyType': 0,
        'columnSize': 0,
        'isEnabled': False,
        'isStructured': False,
        'isUpdated': False,
        'propDisplayName': 'Com Com',
        'propName': 'u4_com_com',
        'propValue': 'Multi-layer',
        'selectedComponent': None,
        'tcProperty': None},
```

Code

```
import json
with open('a.json') as data_file:    
      data = json.load(data_file)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in data], ignore_index=False)
print(df)
```

Error:

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Panda does have a [read_json method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html), is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: I tried with read_json method, it is not giving the right format. I need them, in csv where its readable , meaning, each is considered as header column with its value as row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can first convert your json file into a DataFrame object :

```
df = pd.read_json('file.json')
```

And then convert it with built-in method :
    df.to_csv()

N.B : while reading your JSON you ll have to tweak the reading parameters depending on the json format with the "orient" attribute :

```
df = pd.read_json('file.json', orient="records")
```

orient = "records | index | columns | values | table"

Comment: Thanks, it works but i need each key to be a column and the value to be row